# \ref to table environment appearing as ?? despite everything being correct

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have a very basic table in Latex, which is created and then attempted to be referenced as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!th]
    \centering
    \caption{Credibility of selected library databases.}\label{tab:library-databases}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | p{7.5cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{| c |}{\textbf{Library database}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c |}{\textbf{Credibility}}\\
    \hline
    Birmingham City University Library & Part of Birmingham City University, which was established in the UK in
    1843.
    Contains a large amount of resources including database access.  \\ \hline
    Google Scholar & Used primarily to access literature already hosted on other library databases.
    The site does not contain the ability to restricting searching to only peer-reviewed databases, and thus
    could have unreliable content. \\ \hline
    EBSCOhost Research Databases & EBSCOhost hosts high-quality, peer-reviewed content from publishers
    recognised by library professionals. \\ \hline
    IEEE Xplore & Launched in May 2000, this resource primarily contains peer-reviewed materials published by the Institute of Electrical and
    Electronics Engineers (IEEE) and other partners.
    As the resourced are peer reviewed, they can be seen as reliable.\\ \hline
    ResearchGate & ResearchGate restricts its users to published researchers and people at recognised
    institutions and is a widely accredited library database. \\ \hline
    JSTOR & Part of ITHAKA, a non-profit organisation.
    A digital library including thousands of academic journals, books, and primary source documents. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Several library databases which will be used have been 
identified, and can be found in Table~\ref{tab:library-databases}.

\end{document}
```

The table itself is generated fine and is given an incremental number in the form of `Table n` as it should. However, this is appearing in the outputted PDF as ??, after multiple compilations of the code:

[image]

This seems like such a basic thing to do, yet I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't simply `\ref` the created table.

Oddly, it works fine when I create the table in a `figure` environment, but I need to have a List of Tables for this particular submission and need to be able to create tables in a `table` environment as a result, as my tables and figures need to be seperate.

My LaTeX distro is MikTeX if that is of any use.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: In particular, do please reveal which document class you employ.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to TSE as you can see :) I have added an MWE

Comment: your example resolves to a reference to Table 1 on the second run. [see this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O0G4.png)

Comment: show the log file that you get from the second run

Comment: The document itself is very long and the log file is huge, but here is the log file up until the error (LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:library-databases' on page 3 undefined on inputine 92.) ignore the unidentified control sequence errors they'll be fixed eventually https://pastebin.com/NwttRta1

Comment: Does your MWE still have the `??`?  That log file won't be very big.

Comment: No the log file for your original document is not useful, please show the log you get for the example posted here so we can compare it and try to reproduce.